# Macro VBA more fluid

Tags: vba, ms-word

I made a macro on Ms-Word and i would like to make the program a little more fluid, I created a progressive bar and it stops me continually.
Sometimes it sticks to a percentage and after a while gets 100% all together ...
In excel I put the function `Wait`
I tried to use it on Ms-Word but do an error, is there another function?

Comment: Can't help a lot without seeing the code. Add `DoEvents` after incrementing the progress-bar to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried to use this but it does not work:
`Start = timer
Do While timer <start + 1
     DoEvents
Loop`
I only stop the macro without updating time
To mark the time in the progressive bar I used: Lib "Kernel32" ()